# Returning procedures values in Scheme

Tags: scheme, procedure

I try to call and take value of a procedure with code below

```
(define main (x y)  ((< x y) (p1 x) (p2 y)))
(p1 x) returns 'first, (p2 y) returns 'second
```

however in main there is nothing to return.

how can i solve this ? i try to use let and lambda but i failed.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would define `p1` and `p2` as:

```
(define (p1 thing) 'first)
(define (p2 thing) 'second)
```

and then `main` becomes:

```
(define (main x y)
  (if (< x y)
      (p1 x)
      (p2 y)))
```

if you really need to use `let` and `lambda` then this would work:

```
(define (main x y)
  (let ((p1 (lambda (thing) 'first))
        (p2 (lambda (thing) 'second)))
    (if (< x y)
        (p1 x)
        (p2 y))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant this?

```
(define (main x y)  (if (< x y) (p1 x) (p2 y)))
```

Comment: actually i use if but nothing change, it is still cannot return values.. i also used cond for each condition.. but i cannot get 'f and 't.. moreover they are not #f and #t. they are elements.

Comment: I changed outputs of procedures for better understanding

Comment: what's `p1` and `p2`? post the code. What's `x`, and `y`? post an example of _exactly_ what output value is expected, given a sample input.

Comment: thank you oscar.. you were right at the beginning.. p1 and p2 definitions are wrong so i cannot get the value. right now working.